# Button - Textview click event issue - Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-activity, textview

I have a list of buttons in my activity_main, Once i clicked on Button_A it is taking me to the next list of buttons layout for eg. Button_A1.

And once i clicked Button_A1 it should show me the text which i have written in text_view. But here its getting failed. Once i Clicked in Button_A1, it showing like "your app is stopped". Can you guys help me on this, as i am new on this platform.

```
    **Button_A1.xml:**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="Button_A1" />
    </LinearLayout>


**button_A1.java:**

public class Ov1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ov1);
    }
}
```

Do i have to give activity entry in manifest.xml. Please help me on this..

Button_A  ---->   Button_A1  ----> Textview

Comment: Please provide full code, the Ov1 code and your layout .Also specify what you want more clear please .

Answer (score 1):

> Clicked in Button_A1, it showing like "your app is stopped"

Because `Button_A1` method is not available in `Ov1` class. add method as:

```
public void Button_A1(View view) {
    ////
}
```

**NOTE:** To make `TextView` click-able need to add  `android:clickable="true"` attribute  in `TextView` xml

Comment: @akarsh WT*!!! plz go and search how to work in `android` or refer any other demo example

Comment: @M D  -  yes man.. I know you are having excellent knowledge on this, So for you it may sounds funny.